# renaming tailwindcss class that interferes with another library

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a project built with tailwindCSS and i need to include external css from other library which interferes with some of the tailwind classes. Actually i have found workaround for some of the issues, but still cannot resolve the problem with the .container class.

I know i can use prefix in tailwind classes (setting it from tailwind config file), but that means i will have to change all used tailwind classes which is not reasonable solution knowing how big is the project. I also cannot change the name of the class that is used from another library (it has to be loaded via CDN). So the only solution i can think of is renaming the tailwind .container class. I tried something like this:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      className: 'my-container',
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

but it doesn't seem to work and I cannot find anything in the docs.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do then is this:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/QUMCP8zmD4?file=css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.containerAlias {
  @apply container
}
```

It will basically alias the .container for you without adding the conflicting class, but won't disallow anyone from using it either.

Maybe a custom plugin if the above does not work. but I am not you can customize corePlugins. This it the reason what you are trying to do does not work. The container is just an empty object in the default theme. ".container" is a core plugin now.